# Why didn't S.H.I.E.L.D. help Tony Stark in Iron Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

I have recently rewatched the Iron Man movies, and I noticed something that bugged me. Towards the beginning of the first movie, Tony Stark is captured and imprisoned in a cave for quite some time (not sure how many days, but at least a couple). To get out, he has to build his own suit and fight his way out, etc, etc. This is fine in the context of the first movie. However in the context of the larger MCU, or at least the Iron Man part of it, this is weird.

In the second movie we learn that Howard Stark (Tony's dad) was a founder of S.H.I.E.L.D. which means they have known Tony probably his whole life, especially given his abilities which could (and do) prove to be very valuable to them. My question is, with the knowledge of Stark being in captivity, why did S.H.I.E.L.D. not act in the first movie? Had it not been for the work that the captors wanted Tony to do, he may not have escaped, and we wouldn't have Iron Man.

In-universe, why didn’t S.H.I.E.L.D. do anything?

Comment: *"..especially given his abilities.."* By 'abilities' DYM the incipient alcoholism or the womanising? That's about the only of Tony's talents of which S.H.I.E.L.D. would have been aware prior to Tony creating the Iron Man suit (& using it for 'good').

Comment: In a comic that was released at the time and  that has now been retconned out of canon, SHIELD was not allowed to operate internationally at the time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You're kidding right?! He is a genius weapons designer lol he quite literally had the best weapons in the world before the suit. If you notice after he becomes an "Avenger" he starts designing a lot of stuff for S.H.I.E.L.D. so clearly he was valuable and continues to be.

Comment: @phantom42 interesting! I wonder why they took it out... would definitely clear up that plot hole. Because in the movies they are clearly operating all over, you can see various maps with markings in Africa and Russia throughout the movies.

Comment: *"He is a genius weapons designer.."* Yes! While Tony was a womanising drunkard, any organisation would have regarded him as a liability. The only thing more dangerous than a genius, is a genius who's almost permanently sozzled.

Comment: In the comic, Fury reminds Coulson of the "H" in SHIELD, and the fact that it stands for "Homeland". The problem is that the original tie-in comics painted SHIELD as a fairly new organization, which was changed by the time CA1 came out.

Comment: [fury explains the "H"](https://youtu.be/2FxSLxxckZs?t=35s)  and later [coulson comes up with the shorter SHIELD name](https://youtu.be/2FxSLxxckZs?t=4m31s)

Comment: Perhaps they **were** acting and just couldn't find him. He was in a cave after all.

Comment: He was a gifted weapons-maker, but his selfishness and callow nature made him unsuitable to be anything more than a vendor. SHIELD probably had had enough of his Dad and that stuff, too. But his experiences moved him past that, both in terms of personal growth and in the tech he was able to produce.

Answer (score 10):

There’s no evidence in the movie that they *could* have rescued Tony. S.H.I.E.L.D. aren’t all-powerful and all-knowing, and Tony was kidnapped in war-torn Afghanistan — note that the US Military, who were operating there at the time and were the organisation meant to be protecting Tony during his visit, also didn’t find him until he escaped.

On whether S.H.I.E.L.D. would have had an interest in rescuing Tony, the entire point of the movie is that before his kidnap experience, Tony is the enthusiastic, very public boss of a weapons manufacturer, more concerned with making money, getting attention, and seducing journalists than anything else.

He doesn’t look like a great candidate for someone who’d *want* to help S.H.I.E.L.D., and he’s pretty high-profile for an organisation that works in secret. Sure, Howard Stark helped found S.H.I.E.L.D. — but as we discover in later Iron Man movies and *Civil War*, Tony’s relationship with his father was somewhat strained.

It’s only the Iron Man technology that Tony invents whilst imprisoned that sparks S.H.I.E.L.D.’s interest in him the first place, and obviously that’s only revealed to the world when and after Tony uses it to escape. (And apparently only came about because Tony was captured in the first place.)

And even once Iron Man is a thing, as Nick Fury says to Tony in *Iron Man 2*, Tony is hardly S.H.I.E.L.D.’s number one priority. They got on plenty fine for decades before Tony Stark’s unique brand of world-saving came along.

Comment: Maybe I'm misremembering it, but they seemed to be playing the organization as somewhat new in that first film. Coulson was remarking that they were still trying to work out the name - he only called it SHIELD at the end.  So at the time of that film, they may have planned SHIELD to be more of a start-up, and changed their mind retroactively later.

Answer (score 6):

**Who says that they weren't doing anything?**

We know from Agent Coulson's requests for a meeting with Tony post-Afghanistan that they were aware that he was missing. Maybe they were looking for him and simply weren't successful? Just because we don't see them trying to find him doesn't mean that they weren't - we don't see the US Army actively looking for him either, but it's safe to assume that they were.

It's also worth noting that there is a pretty popular fan theory that states that the Ten Ring Terrorists were funded by Hydra in an attempt to further "stir the pot" in preparation for Operation INSIGHT. That would mean that SHIELD - infiltrated by Hydra at the time - might have been hindered in their attempts to find Tony, which would explain why they were unable to find him.

But even if that isn't the case, it doesn't seem like too much of a stretch to simply accept the fact that SHIELD were simply unable to find him. It's a big world, and in the grand scheme of things, I don't think finding a playboy industrialist would be all that high up on the list of SHIELD's priorities.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer.

Why would they care?  At this point, Tony Stark is just the head of a company that makes weapons.  He isn't Iron Man yet.  He isn't a hero.  In fact, he is a bit of a dick.

Here is a quote from the marvel [wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Strategic_Homeland_Intervention,_Enforcement_and_Logistics_Division_(Earth-199999)) (emphasis mine):

> The Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement, and Logistics
>   Division is a combined military, scientific research, and espionage
>   agency with a mandate to protect the populace of the world from
>   threats ***beyond the scope of standard national security agencies.***

It seems to be out of their mandate to go rescue a single CEO.  That is something regular government agencies can do.